# UIWebView ignores mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction on iOS 10

Tags: ios, video, uiwebview

I am using a UIWebView to play a local video file. Before iOS 10, the video would load and that play triangle would be displayed on top of it and that would be it. Now it autoplays.

The video is loaded as follows:

```
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:localVideoUrl];
[self.webView loadRequest:request];
```

`mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction` is set to `YES`.

I have tried to wrap my video in HTML and then load it with `loadHTMLString:baseUrl:`, but even though that takes care of the autoplay problem, the web view fails to display a preview image and shows only the play triangle instead. While I could probably get this working by generating my own thumbnail from the first frame of the video and showing that as the poster and then add code to display everything in the correct place and at the right size, that would add a prohibitive amount of complexity and, frankly, the problem is not so serious to warrant that kind of work.

Calling

```
[webview stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: @"document.querySelector('video').pause();"
```

in `webViewDidFinishLoad:` to pause the video also has no effect.

Is there any way to force the web view to wait for the user to initiate playback in this scenario, just like it used to before iOS 10?

Comment: `mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction` is [deprecated](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebviewconfiguration/1614727-mediaplaybackrequiresuseraction?language=objc) in iOS 10. Have you tried to set `mediaTypesRequiringUserActionForPlayback ` to `WKAudiovisualMediaTypeVideo`? What happens if you use this?

Comment: That seems to indeed be the case for `WKWebView`s but not for `UIWebView`s, and I'm using a `UIWebView`.